# Exclamatory symbol (!) value is getting excluded return when decoding the string using powershell statement from batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am reading a file in a loop for parameters (input.txt) which has a encoded a string value and that encoded value will be decoded using the Powershell command however the Exclamatory "!" symbol is getting excluded after decoded.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set input_file=%cd%\input.txt

for /f "token=1-2" %%a in (%input_file%) do (
set param1=%%a
set param2=%%b

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('powershell "[Text.Encoding]::utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('!param2!'))"') do set "decoded=%%i"

echo !decoded!
)

exit /b

:EOF
```

The `Param2` value is `TWF0dCQhMyM=` and it's decoded value should come as `Matt$!3#"` however it is returning `Matt$3#"`

why it is excluding Exclamatory "!" symbol and what will be the solution for this? Please advise

Note: Here, when i get the variable value like this %variable_name% it didn't work , only when i use !variable_name! it is working

Comment: Remove the `EnableDelayedExpansion` keyword and replace `echo !decoded!` with either `echo %%i` or `call echo %%decoded%%`. BTW - you also need to investigate whether the decoded value may contain other symbols that have special meaning for batch - especially `%&^|<>;"`

Comment: @Magoo Hi, I have tried it,  'echo %%i' returned '%i' and 'call echo %%decoded%%' returned no value('Echo is off')

Comment: Always happens when I don't test it... The only reason (almost) for using `delayedexpansion` in batch is to use `!var!` to access the run-time value of a variable as it is being changed within a loop. I mentally inserted a `(` before the `set decoded=` to match the unmatched `)` later in the script. The logical reason for `!decoded!` is that the variable is having its value altered *within the loop*. Physically inserting that `(` would solve the problem **IF** you also change the `!` around `param2` to `%` since `param2` is not being changed within the loop..

Comment: @Magoo Hi, I have added ( ) like below but the loop is getting ended after this statement

` @echo off
REM setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set input_file=%cd%\input.txt

for /f "token=1-2" %%a in (%input_file%) do (
set param1=%%a
set param2=%%b

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('powershell "[Text.Encoding]::utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('%param2%'))"') do set ("decoded=%%i")

echo %decoded%
)

exit /b

:EOF`

Comment: `do set ("decoded=%%i") ` should read `do (set "decoded=%%i")` or `do set "decoded=%%i"`.  `echo %decoded%` should be `call echo %%decoded%%`. The `:EOF` label is understood to be end-of-file for a `goto :eof` statement and should not appear in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Before using `%%i`, you need to disable delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FromBase64=powershell "[Text.Encoding]::utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String"
set "input_file=%cd%\input.txt"

for /f "tokens=1-2" %%a in (%input_file%) do (
  set param1=%%a
  set param2=%%b

  for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('%FromBase64%('!param2!'))"') do (
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    echo(%%i
    endlocal
  )
)

exit /b
```

Or disable delayed expansion at all and avoid the param2 variable

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FromBase64=powershell "[Text.Encoding]::utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String"
set "input_file=%cd%\input.txt"

for /f "token=1-2" %%a in (%input_file%) do (
  set param1=%%a

  for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('%FromBase64%('%%b'))"') do (
    echo(%%i
  )
)

exit /b
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried both method and I am getting the following error 'token=1-2" was unexpected at this time.' is there anything else I need to change ?

Comment: @mathankumarc I only copied your example without testing. It should be "tokens" not "token"